# Getting JSON string from object list using gson

Tags: java, json, rest, gson

Previously my code was just this:

```
objJson = gson.toJson(objList);
return objJson;
```

And I got the string JSON with that return value.

But then I started getting famous **Out Of Memory errors** when the JSON becomes too large.

Then I followed the following post that converts the list of objects into JSON String in an efficient way that OOM errors will be no more:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

So, I have followed the above approach here:

```
public String writeJsonStream(List<MyObj> objList) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(baos,"UTF-8");
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(outputStreamWriter);
    writer.setIndent("  ");
    writer.beginArray();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    for (MyObj myobj : objList) {
        gson.toJson(myobj, MyObj.class, writer);
    }

    String objJson = writer.toString();
    writer.endArray();
    writer.close();
    return objJson;
}
```

But this returning object `com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter@6a9454cd`.

The method `gson.toJson(myobj, MyObj.class, writer);` is of type void and doesn't returns JSON string. So how can I get the JSON string in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are getting the JSON String from `String objJson = writer.toString();`. This is not how you should retrieve it: this code will just call the `toString()` method on the `writer` instance. Since [`toString()` is not overriden](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html) for this object, the result is the default `com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter@6a9454cd`.

What you want to do instead is get the bytes that the `JsonWriter` wrote to the output stream. In your case, you are using a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) so you can call [`toString(charsetName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toString-java.lang.String-) to get the content as a String:

```
public String writeJsonStream(List<MyObj> objList) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(baos,"UTF-8");
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(outputStreamWriter);
    writer.setIndent("  ");
    writer.beginArray();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    for (MyObj myobj : objList) {
        gson.toJson(myobj, MyObj.class, writer);
    }
    writer.endArray();
    writer.close();
    return baos.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

As a side note, you could just use a [`StringWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) instead and get the content with [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html#toString--):

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(stringWriter);
// rest of code
writer.close();
String json = stringWriter.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, converting stream to a static object unfortunately does not avoid OOM problem. In either way, you are trying to allocate/request memory to construct/write that string. You must pipe the resulting stream to another one, or simply consume all the data in that stream by using `BufferedWriter` in some loop or else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change ByteArrayOutputStream to OutputStream and get object from System.out

```
   public String writeJsonStream(List<MyObj> objList) throws IOException {
        OutputStream baos = System.out;
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(baos,"UTF-8");
        JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        writer.setIndent("  ");
        writer.beginArray();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        for (MyObj myobj : objList) {
            gson.toJson(myobj, MyObj.class, writer);
        }

        String objJson = writer.toString();
        writer.endArray();
        writer.close();
        return objJson;
```